# Notification with BigStyle not showing short texts

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating a Download-Notification and using the BigTextStyle of NotificationCompat because the text can get really long, depends on how much you download.

The line of code I am using:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_24dp);

    String notifiactionTitle = res.getString(R.string.notification__download_successful_title);
    builder.setContentTitle(notifiactionTitle);
```

and here I am setting the content text:

```
builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationMessage));
```

The result is, that the notification gets shown if I use a message 
as long as "Items downloaded: xy, x, y, xz, x, zy"

But not if I only have one item: "Item downloaded: xy".

I tested that I can randomly type in characters and it will work, as long
as the message is long enough.

I already fixed this issue with also adding

```
builder.setContentText(notificationMessage);
```

before setting the style and bigtext. But I am curious why I need to
set the content title twice, because the documentation of the 
BigTextStyle().bigMethod clearly says:

> Provide the longer text to be displayed in the big form of the template **in place of** the *content text*.

I assume that if the message isn't long enough it don't uses the bigTextStyle
and instead uses the contentText. 
But why isn't it documented and clearly stated out? Am I missing something?
Does anybody know what happens internally?

Thanks already!

Comment: same thing here